# DataInputStream and OutputStream write/read string with length

Tags: java, io, java-io

How to read `String` with `DataInputStream`, which was stored with this code:

```
DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream (out); // Some other stream
String title = processed.getTitle();
dataOut.writeInt(title.length());
dataOut.writeBytes(title);
```

Comment: Read into? WRONG
You can read FROM - DataInputStream

Comment: Try this link - http://e-geek.pl/. I wrote simle article about stream operations. The drawback it is in Polish and google translator can't handle it very good ;P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read like this.

```
DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream (input);
int length = dataIn.readInt();
byte[] array = new byte[length];
dataIn.read(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ByteArrayOutputStream` and `ByteArrayInputStream` and a byte array as intermediate buffer..

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

// Some other streams
DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream (out); 
String title = processed.getTitle();
dataOut.writeInt(title.length());
dataOut.writeBytes(title);

ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream(in);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
dataOut.writeUTF(title);
// ...
String title = dataIn.readUTF();
```

... provided the title doesn't need more than 65533 bytes when written in this format: see the Javadoc.